# How to re-add pressed/clicked effect to QPushButton?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt-creator, qpushbutton

When I set a background color for a QPushButton at its stylesheet, it loses pressed/clicked effect. How can I fix this? How can I re-add this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. I removed "border" declaration/definition at widget that contains these push buttons. Thus problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

Stylesheets can have pseudo states. To style the pressed state of a push button, you can use something like this as your stylesheet:

```
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: red;
}
```

You can read more about the pseudo-states [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#pseudo-states).

[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton) is an example of customizing a `QPushButton`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use style sheets to customize the look and feel of a QPushButton. There is a great list of examples [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton) showing off what you can do. Specifically, you'll be looking at the "pressed" state:

```
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);
}
```

Comment: AVAST popups and blocks access to the qt-project.org site linked, saying that it's a phishing site.  May want to check it to be sure.